# CGI script not executing every page visit

Tags: cgi, cgi-bin

I have a CGI script that generates a file on the server and then redirects the browser to that newly generated file.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
cat /myspecialdir/foo > /httpd/foo.html
echo "<HTML><HEAD><BODY>"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"CACHE-CONTROL\" CONTENT=\"NO-CACHE\">"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"1; URL=/foo.html\">"
echo "</BODY></HEAD></HTML>"
```

The file /myspecialdir/foo contains some dynamic content that I want to be in /httpd/foo.html.  I then want the script to redirect there after the generation of the new file.

The problem I have is that the script doesn't get new data on every hit from a browser.  For example, if I visit http://myip/cgi-bin/genfoo.cgi the first time in IE the data gets generated and it gets redirected to foo.html.  After that, if I go to the CGI page using the back button, it doesn't re-run and I get redirected to stale data.

How can I force the CGI script to execute even from the back button?

**EDIT**:  I tried doing this with the HTTP headers approach, but this doesn't seem to be working.  Here's the new script, am I missing something?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /myspecialdir/foo > /httpd/foo.txt
printf "Pragma-directive: no-cache\n\n";
printf "Cache-directive: no-cache\n\n";
printf "Cache-control: no-cache\n\n";
printf "Pragma: no-cache\n\n";
printf "Expires: 0\n\n";
printf "Location: /foo.txt\n\n";
printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

All this does when I visit via IE is to print the headers in the page, like so:

Pragma-directive: no-cache

Cache-directive: no-cache

Cache-control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Expires: 0

Location: /BACtrace.txt

Content-type: text/html

**EDIT:**

It turns out this was an issue with the HTTP server I was using (busybox v1.12.1).  I was unable to send the HTTP headers as originally recommended, but I was able to get this to work with a combination of META tags and a setting in IE8 (Tools --> Internet Options --> Browsing History --> Settings Button --> check "Every time I visit a website").

The META tags I used are:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"0\" />"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Pragma-directive\" CONTENT=\"no-cache\"/>"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Cache-directive\" CONTENT=\"no-cache\"/>"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Cache-control\" CONTENT=\"no-cache\"/>"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Pragma\" CONTENT=\"no-cache\"/>"
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"1; URL=/foo.txt\"/>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this **much** easier on yourself by doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /myspecialdir/foo > /httpd/foo.html

printf "Location: /foo.html\n\n";
```

This sends a header to the browser telling it to redirect to `/foo.html` instead of having to load and parse the `<meta>` tags.

**Edit:** You should only send 1 `\n` at the end of each header.  After the entire request, you send 2 of them, like this (broken out for clarity):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /myspecialdir/foo > /httpd/foo.txt
printf "Pragma-directive: no-cache\n";
printf "Cache-directive: no-cache\n";
printf "Cache-control: no-cache\n";
printf "Pragma: no-cache\n";
printf "Expires: 0\n";
printf "Location: /foo.txt\n";
printf "\n";
```

(Also note that the `Content-Type` header isn't included)

Comment: Sorry, Sean, but that doesn't redirect.  All that does is print "Location: /foo.html" in the browser.  Am I missing something?

The new script is:
#!/bin/ash
cat /myspecialdir/foo > /httpd/foo.txt
printf "Location: /foo.txt\r\n";
printf "Pragma-directive: no-cache\r\n"
printf "Cache-directive: no-cache\r\n"
printf "Cache-control: no-cache\r\n"
printf "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
printf "Expires: 0\r\n"

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Sean.  It looks like the server I'm using (httpd from an older BusyBox) breaks this though because it automatically sends the Content-type: text/plain header which prevents my script from sending headers.  So, unforutnately, I have to use META tags.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the browser (and possible proxies) to disable caching of the file with the appropriate HTTP headers:

```
Pragma-directive: no-cache
Cache-directive: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Of course, you'll just add each these in your script like this:

```
printf "Pragma-directive: no-cache\r\n";
```

There's a fair bit of redundancy in these directives.  All are probably not necessary, but it's good to make sure there's something all browsers and proxies out there understand.